# VPS Web Server and VPS MySQL; should I purchase one or both?

Tags: web-hosting

I want to purchase VPS at Dreamhost because I realized that shared hosting is too slow for my site.

But I have one confusion:[image]

I have two options: VPS Web Server and VPS MySQL

Which one is the one that will make my site load faster?

Answer (score 2):

You need the first one, primarily. That's a complete hosting environment.
The MySQL server option is [*only* database hosting](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/DreamHost_PS_MySQL), in case your db needs are great enough that it would be beneficial to split them off.